# Can't use variables set by __init__ outside the functions while still inside the class

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance, init

The code I need to run looks like this:

```
class Trial():

    def __init__(self, prop1 = 0, prop2= 1):
        self.property1 = prop1
        self.property2 = prop2
        
    if self.property1 == 4:
        print("It's working outside too!")

tri = Trial(4, 5)
```

This gives error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

If I don't use self.property1, but just use property1, the same error is generated about property1.

How do I use the variables set inside the __init__ function outside a function while still being inside the class definition? Is that even possible?

Comment: No; that code is executed while the class is still being defined, long before any instance of the class (which is what `self` will refer to) exists.

Comment: `property1` is not a variable; it's an *attribute*. Don't confuse the two just because both are referred to with identifiers.

Comment: don't use variables outside methods in class.

Comment: ` Is that even possible?` - apparently not. WHY do you need/want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, self refers to the instance of the class and you can call it just inside a class. If you want to check for example the value of the property1 outside of the class, you should call it through instance.

```
class Trial():

    def __init__(self, prop1 = 0, prop2= 1):
        self.property1 = prop1
        self.property2 = prop2
    


tri = Trial(4, 5)

if tri.property1 == 4:
    print("It's working outside too!")
```